# How can detect CTRL+V on vue.js in any place without put to many events?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I am trying to capture a ctrl+v event on-site create with vue.js, in this site, there isn't any form but there are a few buttons, so I want to detect the ctrl+v event Independently of if the user did click in any button previously or not.

Is this possible?

How can do it?

Comment: Please don't block pasting, *especially* on password fields. People use password managers. People have passwords that are impractical to type in. People have accessibility needs.

Comment: Edited, I don't want to cancel, I want to detect the ctrl+v on anywhere place, but I don't want to put in every place the event to capture the ctrl+v

Comment: @tadman It's entirely possible to paste to the page. If I go to https://imgur.com/ and paste when I've got an image in my clipboard, it uploads. No focus required.

Comment: @ceejayoz Always presumed they had some kind of invisible yet focused element to capture that, but could be wrong!

Comment: So, could I force the focus of any way?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/paste_event